# how to change the color of function call in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

when define a function sayGreeting, the color is blue

[image]

but when call it, the color is changed

[image]

how to change the color when calling it

I try the the `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` in `settings.json`

but I don't know the token of that.

Comment: install another syntax-highlighter of your choice

Answer (score 0):

set "semanticTokenColorCustomizations" not work perfect

but set "tokenColorCustomizations" additionally

"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
"[Atom One Dark]": {
"functions": "#61afef"
}
}

that would be fine